# "package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)" on RHEL 6.6

Tags: r, rhel, devtools, rhel6

Any advice on how I can get R statistical package devtools installed?

```
>install.packages("devtools",repos="http://cran.rstudio.com", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/home/bckadm/nowackj1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
>
```

Comment: You need to update your R to the newest version (3.3.1 I think)

Comment: `devtools` depends on R ≥ 3.0.2. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html